# Change color of div to match another div using jquery

Tags: jquery

I currently have a total of 4 boxes with the same class and each has its own ID, when any of the boxes are clicked, the background colors of all the boxes should change to that of an assigned div ID.

I do want to have it be a specific color as in the current JS fiddle example, I want it to be what ever color a particular div is.
i.e. #box2 will change color on .click to that of #box1 and #box1 will change to the color of #box4. thus giving the illusion of the boxes moving clockwise. I want this to be usable for an unlimited number of clicks.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.colorbox').click(function () {
                $('#box1').css('background-color', 'blue');
                $('#box2').css('background-color', 'red');
                $('#box3').css('background-color', 'yellow');
                $('#box4').css('background-color', 'green');           
            });
        });
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/YMqyE/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/YMqyE/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.colorbox').click(function () {
            var $b1 = $('#box1'),
                $b2 = $('#box2'),
                $b3 = $('#box3'),
                $b4 = $('#box4'),
                box4Color = $b4.css('background-color');
            $b4.css('background-color', $b3.css('background-color'));
            $b3.css('background-color', $b2.css('background-color'));
            $b2.css('background-color', $b1.css('background-color'));
            $b1.css('background-color', box4Color);

        });
    });
```

Comment: What if jsfiddle is inaccessible? Please post relevant code inside of your answer, or it isn't really an answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.colorbox').click(function () {
        var $OddColorOut = $('#box1').css('background-color');

        $('#box1').css('background-color', $('#box4').css('background-color'));
        $('#box4').css('background-color', $('#box3').css('background-color'));
        $('#box3').css('background-color', $('#box2').css('background-color'));
        $('#box2').css('background-color', $OddColorOut);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thalladay/p92V6/

Comment: Shorter and less efficient. The only reason I var $b1 = etc etc is to avoid creating the same jQuery object twice for each square.

Comment: @MHollis is right, you're performing 8 queries, he's performing 4.

Comment: @MHollis is right, if the goal is performance. My goal was a more straightforward example for someone who prefers less variable creation, and is not as concerned about the performance penalty of doing the extra selections.

Comment: My problem is that you're teaching this novice programmer bad practices. The performance hit of the extra queries is moot in this example, but it wouldn't be if that same code ran 10000 times.   
  
Also, regardless if you create a variable or not, the extra jQuery objects are being created in memory. They still have to go through GC. Your not saving any resources by skipping variable declaration.  
  
There are some nice jQuery performance rules at http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/#cache-jquery-objects